# Failure of geodesic uniqueness - what does it say about the manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic, semi-riemannian-geometry

I am more of a physicist than a mathematician, but this question is properly mathematical rather than physical, even though it is motivated by a physical application; please assume mathematical ignorance (and apologies for any abuse of notation *and terminology*).

Take a standard general relativist's spacetime manifold $M$, i.e. a semi-Riemannian/Lorentzian paracompact Hausdorff manifold such that $\forall p\in M$ there is an unique (timelike) geodesic $\gamma_{p,\vec{v}}$ through $p$ with a given velocity $\vec{v}$ (i.e. for each $\vec{v}\in T_{p}M$).

The specific question is this.

If, after unspecified cut & join operations on $M$, one finds that for some $p\in M, \vec{v}$ there are at least two (timelike) *originally geodesic* curves through $p$:

- What properties of the manifold required for uniqueness theorems to apply (e.g Picard-Lindelöf/Cauchy-Lipschitz) are no longer satisfied (and specifically, why), and thus where do the uniqueness arguments break down?
- Are there some properties which necessarily have been violated, or are there one or more merely sufficient violations?

I am most interested in the answers for excisions limited to the interiors of 4D regions within $M$, but pedagogical examples of other cases are also welcome.

**1 Aug 16 - Additional Illustrations & Commentary**

For clarification, as requested.

[image]
[image]

For definiteness: initial manifold is Minkowksi space and $\gamma_{L}, \gamma_{R}$ are geodesics with $\vec{v}=0$ in the chosen frame, but the question remains for Lorentzian manifolds in general, as originally described; two spatial dimensions suppressed.

Specify two tubes as sphere $\times$ the solid lines; excise the *interiors* (stippled regions) and identify the surfaces of the spheres as indicated *at equal* $t$; after the cut and glue*...

Fig 1: The walls of the excised regions are not parallel; geodesics $\gamma_{L}, \gamma_{R}$ are initally distinct, but the identification of $p, q$ creates a Y and the geodesics can only continue on the LHS; there appear to be two geodesics through $p, q$

Fig 2: The walls of the excised regions are parallel; $\gamma_{L}, \gamma_{R}$ cross - or continue on the same side without any rationale for going one way or the other.

**Thoughts on what is wrong with the resulting manifold**
(Previously omitted to keep the question short and clean.) In excising the interiors of the 4D regions specified, a 3D boundary is created (time x 2D spatial). The indentification stated (which is traditional in physics literature) is purely spatial therefore the boundary does not seem to be completely removed.

Whether, if true, this affects the differential structure and in such a way as to nullify the geodesic nature of one or more curves I don't know: in Minkowski space the metric is constant and it is hard for me to see how the cut & glue is problematic from this perspective, or in the more general case *if* derivatives are defined for closed intervals on $\mathbb{R}$, which they can be, though I can see there *might* be a problem with the total derivative on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$.

In Fig 1 I do not think the solution is that the RHS line can be rotated to match the LHS because the implied homeomorphism does not, AFAICT, result in the neighbouhood $p,q$ becoming homemorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ because an extra gluing step is required. Is there a legitimate way to do this? That could be part of the answer; I don't know - hence the original question.

Fig 2 is most illustrative because at $p,q$ the tangents are parallel, so upon identification there is no need for any "rotation", but is the neighbouhood of $p,q$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{4}$?

**Conjecture**

I conjecture - and am trying to *prove* - that the excised regions have a unique geometry if local geodesic existence and uniqueness is to be preserved through the cut and glue operation, and that geometry is some (smooth, closed, etc.) surface $\times$ a geodesic congruence; my problem with proving it is that I think I can see something's wrong if the geometry is incorrect, but I can't identify the right mathematical concepts to pin down the issue.

* I deliberately used "join" previously because I was aware of standard "cut and glue" methods and did not wish to imply any such that might have been incompatible with the motivation of the question.

Comment: There are two notions of non-uniqueness, and parts of your question seem to assume one or the other. Clarification would be welcome. :) First, if $p$ and $q$ are points (not necessarily distinct), there may exist distinct timelike geodesics starting at $p$ and passing through $q$. (Gravitational lensing is a physical example.) Second, there might conceivably exist a point $p$, a timelike tangent vector $v$, and distinct geodesics starting at $p$ with initial velocity $v$. (Even in the Lorentzian case, I believe this can't happen if the metric is smooth.)

Comment: Happy to clarify. I don't mean geodesics from $p$ to $q$ (I left out the "and not CTC's" for brevity) as in e.g. lensing; I mean the latter. AFAI understand it, the geodesic existence and uniqueness theorem guarantees (subject to the conditions I am asking about) that there is only one through $p$ with timelike tangent vector $v$, per Wikipedia statement <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Existence_and_uniqueness>. (Didn't understand the "Even in the Lorenztian case..." part. NB I have been visualising in Minkowski space but am interested in full generality)

Comment: For a Riemannian metric of class $C^{1}$, for each point $p$ and each tangent vector $v$ at $p$, there is a unique geodesic starting at $p$ with initial velocity $v$. I believe the same is true for Lorentzian metrics ("Even in the Lorentz case..."). If you perform surgery and lose uniqueness in this strong sense, then, it means the surgery didn't respect the metric structure: After surgery, there is a point $p$ for which no neighborhood of $p$ has a $C^{1}$ Lorentz metric.

Comment: OK, if this comment doesn't suffice, I'll amend the question. Minkowski space. tube A cylinder parallel to $t$; tube B similar but, say, $\pi/8$ to the vertical. Excise interiors. Identify spatial surfaces as equal$t$ and consider geodesics parallel to $t$ a) $\gamma_A$ on LHS of A, and b) $\gamma_B$ somewhere to the RHS of B at $t=t_0$ so $\gamma_B$ intersects B at some $\tau>t_0$. How does metric structure fail where the two geodesics meet? i.e. you're saying the answer is "metric structure is lost" but not how, where etc. I'd appreciate details - this is the essence of the question.

Comment: How would you even define Lorentzian geodesics if you do not have a twice differentiable Lorentzian metric on a twice differentiable smooth manifold?

Comment: The geodesics are present initially; if there only appears to be an intersection afterwards and it's because they (or one of them) is no longer a geodesic is a possibility. Again, the question becomes given the example construction, where and why is differentiability lost?

Comment: Not sure I perfectly understand the proposed construction, but: 1. The gluing does not yield a smooth Lorentzian metric for the same reason the analogous gluing doesn't give a smooth Riemannian metric: There's no isometry between the inside and outside of a tube. 2. Even if the smooth structure is ironed out (ahem) after surgery, when the two geodesics meet, they're not tangent, but instead meet at angle $\pi/8$. By analogy, draw two parallel lines on a sheet of paper; remove a sector, and close up to make a cone. Where the formerly-parallel geodesics meet, they meet non-tangentially.

Comment: :) Something like (2) had occurred to me, but doesn't it assume that the $\pi/8$ line has been rotated to align with $t$ on the LHS (or vice versa)? Homeomorphism of the neighbouhood at each pair of joined points to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is not all obvious (to me). Don't follow the isometry of "inside and outside" point - there is no inside. My thought: join specified in comment is 2D spatial, but the boundary created by excising a 4D region is time x 2D and the identification in the $t$ direction is missing, so there is still some sort of boundary: Q - is this where smoothness fails? Exactly why?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Would it help if I added some diagrams for particular cases to the question?

Comment: @JulianMoore: Yes, if you can add diagrams, I think that would help. :) If I understand the proposed construction, the _act of gluing_ amounts to rotating, as in the cone analogy. As to the inside/outside issue, I'm thinking of gluing the outsides of two disks in the plane (not metrically smooth) versus gluing the inside of a disk to the outside (metrically smooth). (Separately, I'm not abandoning the question, but it may be a day or few before I have time to make substantive commentary, assuming I have anything to add.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Illustrations and commentary added. Thanks for the note about contributing further: if you do have more to add it will be very much appreciated, and waiting a day or two is not a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qualitatively, gluing in Riemannian or Lorentzian geometry is a rigid affair. Think of paper, or the plastic used to manufacture beverage bottles: It's flexible, but not stretchable.

- A (closed) disk of paper admits a smooth flat Riemannian structure (with boundary); the exterior, i.e., the paper outside that (open) disk, also admits a smooth Riemannian structure. Their union, glued along their common boundary, admits a smooth Riemannian structure: the structure of the original flat sheet of paper before the disk was excised.
- The union of two flat disks (closed, of equal radius) attached along their boundary does not acquire a smooth Riemannian structure from the geometries of the individual disks: Along the boundary, the curvature is infinite, albeit in such a way that the integral of the curvature over the boundary is finite.
- Similarly, the union $M$ of two exteriors of disks (open, of equal radius) fails to acquire a smooth Riemannian structure along their common circle boundary $C$. The resulting singular space exhibits non-unique geodesics through each point of $C$: A line tangent to $C$ in one "sheet" is geodesic in any reasonable sense; each point $p$ of $C$ lies on two such lines in $M$, giving four geodesics (the lines, and the "crossovers"). Arguably, $C$ itself is geodesic, as well (e.g., it is the fixed point set of an isometry), though $C$ does consist entirely of points where the metric structure of $M$ is not Riemannian.
- A square of paper admits a smooth flat Riemannian structure (with boundary). By contrast with the disk, the union of two squares attached along their boundary does acquire a smooth Riemannian structure along the *edges* of the squares (a $2 \times 1$ rectangle of flat paper may be folded in half!), but topological sphere obtained by attaching two squares along their boundaries still has infinite curvature *at the corners*, in such a way that the integral of the curvature over each vertex ($2\pi$ minus the angle incident at that vertex, a.k.a., the angular defect) is finite.
- As mentioned in the comments, a sector of a disk (think Pac Man, not pie slice) can be glued into a cone. The resulting space is smooth (and flat!) except at the vertex. Lines that were parallel in the flattened sector but that meet along the "joint" always fail to be tangent.

Though each of the preceding examples gives a topological manifold (which admits a smooth structure), each paper model has "singularities", points $p$ at which the "pieces of geometry near $p$" do not comprise a smooth Riemannian disk.

The situation with Lorentzian metrics is similar, though more delicate: A Riemannian metric is isotropic to first order at each point, while a Lorentzian metric has a future-pointing light cone. That said, I believe the qualitative features of the preceding examples carry over to the Lorentzian case.

With the clarification of your diagrams (thank you!), my cone example still appears partly analogous to the left-hand picture: In the identified space, *the green curve is not smooth*, but instead changes direction abruptly at $p = q$. (After gluing, the two cylinder boundaries are identified; the green curve is tangent "in the future" thanks to $p$, but not tangent "in the past" thanks to $q$.)

Additionally, the left-hand identification is not spatially smooth along the cylinder boundary, for the same reason that gluing the exteriors of two open disks (of equal radius) does not yield a smooth Riemannian structure along the boundary circle.

The right-hand diagram appears to be analogous to the third example above (the glued exteriors of disks). The analogy isn't perfect, since your geodesics are timelike rather than spacelike, but (modulo my Lorentzian non-expertise) the metric in the spatial directions is not smooth along the curving cylinder.

In summary, neither proposed gluing appears to acquire a smooth Lorentzian metric, and in the left-hand diagram, the green curve is not properly tangent (in the past) to the red curve.

Comment: Very grateful! I think I get some of the principles; extended discussion in comments deprecated - would you be willing to chat further? (If so, how to arrange?) Summary/questions. Given manifold drilled and glued (spatially) as described geodesic uniqueness fails because Picard-Lindelöf etc. requires ($C^{n+1}$, or is it n?) differentiability for DE's $O(n)$, but the result has $\infty$ [not defined] curvature  thus total derivative undefined & curvature is $\infty$ because "rigid gluing" creates an angle deficit. [continues...]

Comment: However, IFF the links (cf Dehn surgery drilling?) are geodesic & everywhere parallel, no angle deficit occurs & result has finite curvature, derivatives are defined, Picard-Lindelöf applies & geodesic uniqueness is preserved. **QUESTION** What theorems are needed/how would I *prove* all this from principles outlined? (*Rigid gluing* seems like a requirement that $T_{p}M, T_{q}M$ be aligned; is that correct? Sadly, I also don't "get" why the union of two disks has $\infty$ curvature at the join, and Googling hasn't helped. *All that said,I* really *appreciate the effort in answering.* [cont.]

Comment: Still unclear about etiquette: such a nice answer, even though I would appreciate more detail, should I "accept" it nonetheless? [End :)]

Comment: Happy to discuss this further, but I'm only available on weekends for the next two weeks, and only sporadically after. (End of the summer....) As time permits, I'll edit this answer. Briefly, for geodesic uniqueness, surgery must result in a $C^{2}$ metric. Dehn surgery is topological, not metric. (You're welcome to email (profile -> web site -> address). If you have JSTOR access: [Paper Surface Geometry](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.120.06.487) may be of interest. As for upvoting/accepting, it's not necessary/expected unless this actually answers your question. :)

Comment: (If you don't have JSTOR access, I can email a copy of the paper.)

Comment: Thank you.  I'll email you shortly. (I don't have full JSTOR access so can only read a limited no of articles online - and it would be good to have a pdf.)